# RHQ JBoss operations network (JON) and monitoring network

Tags: networking, jboss, performance-testing, rhq

I wonder if JON/RHQ could be used to monitor bottlenecks in the infrastructure with regards to network (firewalls, switches etc.) during loadtesting with i.e. LoadRunner.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not use the built in monitoring capability of LoadRunner, which would then allow you to pull all of your business data (response times and data points) together with your monitoring data into the same data set for analysis purposes?

By having decoupled data sets you are making your challenge of identifying root cause that much more difficult.   If you were planning on exporting data from JON|RHQ to LoadRunner analysis or exporting both to a tool such as SAS, SPSS or R for statistical analysis you would be able to reconcile the decoupled data sets.  (see manual for information on importing data into Analysis for the types and formats supported)